# How to inherit from the DbContext Class

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am working on MVC and in the model I created a class that uses Entity
 Framework. I am trying to inherit from DBContext class but it is showing
 an error saying: "The type or Namespace name DBContext doesn't exist". I also
 added the "System.data.Entity " namespace.

Example like :

```
 public Class SampleEF :DBContext //Showing error
{

}
```

Can you please tell me how to use the DBContext class to work with EF?

Comment: Hint: It's DbContext, not DBContext.

Comment: +1, I don't see why this question was downvoted. He showed us what he wanted to do, that he tried something specific, gave us the error and came to us. Naturally he could have looked around a bit more, but still, someone else will probably run into the same issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly Add Reference to `System.Data.Entity` in your project by Right Click your project in Solution explorer and Select Add Reference. Then use the `using` statement as below:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
```

Then write your Context Class as:

```
public Class SampleEF : DbContext 
{

}
```

Ref: [Using DbContext in EF 4.1 Part 1: Introduction and Model](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/27/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-1-introduction-and-model.aspx)

Comment: it's is good. and one thing consider to upvote and accept the answer here if it help you to solve your problem, it will encourage other to help..

Answer (score 0):

Install Entity framework by using the command "install-package entityframework" from Tools > Library Package Manager > Package Manager Console  . . .it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if adding the reference didn't work out:

```
public Class SampleEF : System.Data.Entity.DbContext 
{

}
```